# Configuring streamparse in remote Storm cluster

Tags: apache-storm

Bit confused in configuring remote cluster in streamparse.Streamparse works fine in localhost .But dont no how to set up a cluster,my config.json is:

```
{
    "library": "",
    "topology_specs": "topologies/",
    "virtualenv_specs": "virtualenvs/",
    "envs": {
        "prod": {
            "user": "nandaraj",
            "nimbus": "localhost",
            "workers": ["localhost"],
            "log": {
                "path": "",
                "max_bytes": 1000000,
                "backup_count": 10,
                "level": "info"
            },
            "virtualenv_root": "/data/virtualenvs"
        }
    }
}
```

First I have tried it with localhost in nimbus and worker and getting the error:

> [localhost] Executing task '_create_or_update_virtualenv'
>
> Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host:
>   localhost), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode
>
> Aborting. Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host:
>   localhost), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode
>
> Fatal error: One or more hosts failed while executing task
>   '_create_or_update_virtualenv'
>
> Aborting. One or more hosts failed while executing task
>   '_create_or_update_virtualenv'

After that I have tried with a ip of a computer (in place of localhost for worker)  in the same LAN and getting the same  error.

> [192.168.61.41] Executing task '_create_or_update_virtualenv'
>
> Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host:
>   192.168.61.41), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode
>
> Aborting. Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host:
>   192.168.61.41), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode
>
> Fatal error: One or more hosts failed while executing task
>   '_create_or_update_virtualenv'
>
> Aborting. One or more hosts failed while executing task
>   '_create_or_update_virtualenv'

I have installed streamparse in server and localhost with same version and  lein of same version and jdk7 on both server and  localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following in fabfile.py (you have to set the env)

```
from fabric.api import env
env.use_ssh_config = True
env.password = 'server_password' 
from streamparse.ext.fabric import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines in config.json in case you are trying to submit the topology to the cluster in same host:

```json
{
    "use_ssh_for_nimbus": true,
    "virtualenv_root": "/data/virtualenvs/",
    "use_virtualenv": false
}
```

See also [streamparse/quickstart.rst](https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/blob/552c3443f5d618591a4cf87a049a0ccca8dd36fe/doc/source/quickstart.rst#disabling--configuring-virtualenv-creation)

Answer (score 0):

By this problem you should edit ur `~/.ssh/config` file for a public/private ssl key visit from the client you submit your code to the server of storm cluster. You can check whether ur `~/.ssh/config` file works by no password ssh visit from your client to the nodes in storm cluster one by one.